# js tabs by table

Tags: javascript, html-table, tabs

I have js and html code, but this does not work.
How to get it to work?

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

    $('div.tabs div.tabs-nav a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
        $('div.tabs div.tabs-nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
</script>

<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-nav">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" href="#tab-1">link-1</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" href="#tab-2">link-2</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" href="#tab-3">link-3</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" href="#tab-4">link-4</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" href="#tab-5">link-5</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" href="#tab-6">link-6</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I'm too lazy to test.

Comment: Sample take from http://vremenno.net/examples/jquery-tabs/multiple.html

Comment: With ul, li works, but with table, td not works (

Comment: I did mine with just a navigation menu and a simple `<div>` structure. I'm pretty sure it works with tables, so copy it if you wish: http://blender3d.github.com/Bindery/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to add tabs to your page.  Just use jQuery UI and the tabs module.  Here's the working example, just view source and copy it out:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

You can style them using jQuery UI themes:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Enjoy :)